# I don't know what RSpec assigns does, and my tests are failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm following along in the book, Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec, and it makes use of `assigns`:

```
it "assigns the requested Category to @category" do
  category = FactoryGirl.create(:category)
  binding.pry
  get :edit, id: category
  expect(assigns(:category)).to eq category
end
```

However, my tests are failing so I'm using pry to dig in (as seen above)

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_1>)> category
=> #<Category id: 83, name: "Example  category", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-03-31 12:25:45", updated_at: "2014-03-31 12:25:45", amount: nil, group_id: nil, amount_in: nil, amount_out: nil>
```

..ok, category is fine. Great! But, I'm not really sure what `assigns` actually does and couldn't find documentation on it as I don't really know where it belongs to (RSpec? FactoryGirl?). Here's the result I'm getting anyway:

```
[2] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_1>)> assigns(:category)
=> nil
```

..and it's nil. Can someone please point me in the right direction here if it's something obvious, and even explain just a little what `assigns` actually does here (or is meant to do), would be very much appreciated. Also, where is the documentation for `assigns`?

Comment: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#assignkey-val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assigns` is actually part of the Rails functional testing framework. It's a way to access the instance variables (the `@` variables) that you assign in your controller - so `assigns(:category)` will be nil if you never set `@category` in your controller action.

For more information about `assigns`, check out [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-four-hashes-of-the-apocalypse) of the Ruby on Rails guide to testing. The full documentation for it is in the [ActionController::TestCase documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you should expect from the assign after calling your controller, is to have the value that the controller sets to the instance variable. You could see it like using @category. So the category created with FactoryGirl is not equals to the one created by your controller (in this case seems your action is returning nil value in your instance variable)